# Using Spark to save data to Cassandra

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, datastax

Now in my current architecture I have a module which is responsible for writing/reading data to and from Cassandra, and module responsible for downloading data. Recently I started using Datastax and Spark. I want to do some transformations on new acquired data. What's the right take on this problem? Do I use my module for storing data and do Spark calculations separately, or send downloaded data directly to Spark using Spark Streaming and in a job save both the orginal data and transformed data to Cassandra? I'm operating on stock quotes so it's a lot of data downloaded continuously and a lot of transformations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, its better to keep it separated.

first store the raw data then process it.
its easier to scale and maintain each component later.

for example: if you want to change something in your downloading module like adding a new download sources or fix a bug, it wont affect the data processing done in spark, and changing something in the code running on spark wont have any effect(or introduce a bug) on the raw data you downloaded.

Comment: Module that downloads data from different soucces unifies data before sending it further so it's not a problem. I'm simply concerned about Spark acting as a module managing data storage. It simplifies architecture because module for data management will be redundant as Spark would do saving, transformations and also reading through SparkSQL. My question is if it is intended to do all that?

Comment: @PawełSzychiewicz, it will get complicated if you decide to store the downloaded and processed data in a different location like aws s3.  
  
you need to separate the raw data you download from the processed data your spark spits out. they are completely different.

i suggest having a module for downloading and storing data,
a module for unifying the data, and a module to process the data.

with this setup it will be easy to maintain each part, and in future if you decide to change something it will be very easy to replay all the historic data and run it throw the pipe again